# How to use codesign command

Tags: certificate, code-signing, codesign, p12

I am trying to use codesign command to sign bundle.

First of all I have got p12 file and I have imported into my keychain.

However when I try to use codesign like this:

```
codesign -v --force --verify --deep --verbose --sign <ID> <MyApp.app>
```

It says 'no identity found'. The identity field I got it from [image]

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are on iOS? Can you explain what `bundle` is?

Comment: I finally exported the p12 file again and it worked so probably i did something wrong first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run `codesign` command, you need to unlock your keyChain, either by clicking on unlock on the keychain app or run `security unlock-keychain`, otherwise you can get inconsistent result because sometimes the keychain is already unlocked, sometimes not.

You might also need to include the `--keychain` option in your codesign command, depending on your configuration.

You can verify if the identity is available in your current shell environment by 
`security find-identity -p codesigning`